# Two mice, two motion speeds

Tags: usb, mouse, bluetooth, windows-8.1-preview

I have two mice attached to my notebook on the docking station: one BT and one USB. I expect they have different resolution or sensitivity because BT one moves cursor over the screen faster than the USB one.

I know I can adjust motion speed in mouse settings but that's a global setting that changes behaviour for both at the same time.

**Is it possible to set motion speed individually for each of them?**

P.S. I'm using both because I'm having some issues with USB mouse on Windows 8.1 that erratically detects single clicks as double clicks. Then I switch to BT. But after a while I prefer my *full weight* USB again and switch back. And I don't want to mingle with setting every time I do so.

Comment: do the mice themselves have some sensitivity/res change option onboard?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: "on board" as some sort of a physical switch? They're Microsoft Intellimouse Explorer 3.0 and Microsoft Notebook Presenter Mouse 8000 respectively.

Comment: yeah, some mice have that

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, install a Logitech mouse, with Logitech SetPoint software. You don't have to use the Logitech; you just need SetPoint. It will let you set options, including speed, for all mice independently.